# generic method to sort lists of sealed class children

Tags: kotlin, generics

I want to cast my list to the class type that I receive from the method argument.

basically I want to order my list based on a field that exists in the ClassA.
how to achieve this?

```kotlin
sealed class ParentClass
data class ClassA(fieldInClassType: Int) : ParentClass()
data class ClassB(fieldInClassType: Int) : ParentClass()
```

I have a list of ClassA and ClassB and I want to create a generic method to sort them. in my old code, I used `when()` but it looks ugly.

so I am trying to refactor the code in a generic method. This is what I have now

```
private fun <T: ParentClass>foo(data: List<T>,  classType: Class<T>){
    val list = data as classType
    list.sortedBy{it.fieldInClassType}
}
```

Comment: Where is `List<Any>`? Can you provide some more info about what you want to do?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu updated the question. please check again and let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: both ```ClassA``` and ```ClassB``` are childern of ```parentClass``` which is sealed class

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a sealed class, you can utilize `when` in order to ensure your code covers all potential children classes.

```kotlin
sealed class ParentClass
data class ClassA(val fieldInClassType: Int) : ParentClass()
data class ClassB(val fieldInClassType: Int) : ParentClass()

fun foo(data: List<ParentClass>): List<ParentClass> {
    return data.sortedBy {
        when (it) {
            is ClassA -> it.fieldInClassType
            is ClassB -> it.fieldInClassType
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    val sorted = foo(listOf(ClassA(4), ClassB(1)))
    sorted.forEach { println(it.javaClass) }
}
```

Output:

> ClassB
>
> ClassA

However....

If all the child classes will have that field, use an interface:

```kotlin
interface MyInterface {
    val fieldInClassType: Int
}

sealed class ParentClass : MyInterface
data class ClassA(override val fieldInClassType: Int) : ParentClass()
data class ClassB(override val fieldInClassType: Int) : ParentClass()

fun foo(data: List<ParentClass>): List<ParentClass> {
    return data.sortedBy { it.fieldInClassType }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively define abstract value in `ParentClass` itself, so no need for an interface.
`sealed class ParentClass { abstract val fieldInClassType: Int } `